# Google Maps Api - how to plot line length in elevation graph

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-visualization, geojson

I have a map which displays elevation graphs in infowindows, for some lines.  Is there any way to display the line length along the horizontal axis of the graph?

Here is the code used for creating the elevation graph:

```
//Loading the GeoJSON file containing the lines
lines = new google.maps.Data();
lines.loadGeoJson('http://googledrive.com/host/0B55_4P6vMjhITEU4Ym9iVG8yZUU/lines.geojson');
lines.setMap(map)


//Setting the infowindow content
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
{content: '<div class = "corp" style="width: 300px; height: 200px">' + '<div id = "elevation_chart">' + '</div>' + '</div>'}
)

//Displaying the infowindow when a line is clicked
lines.addListener('click', function (event) {
    infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng)
    infowindow.setMap(map)
    drawPath(event.feature.getGeometry().getArray());
});


//Invoking the elevation service
elevator = new google.maps.ElevationService()


//Defining the path for which to plot the elevation
function drawPath(path, type) {
chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('elevation_chart'));

var pathRequest = {
    'path': path,
    'samples': 256
};

elevator.getElevationAlongPath(pathRequest, plotElevation);
}


function plotElevation(results, status) {
if (status != google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) {
    return;
}
var elevations = results;

var elevationPath = [];
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    elevationPath.push(elevations[i].location);
}

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Sample');
data.addColumn('number', 'Elevation');
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    data.addRow(['', elevations[i].elevation]);
}


document.getElementById('elevation_chart').style.display = 'block';
chart.draw(data, {
    legend: 'none',
    titleY: 'Elevation (m)'
});
}
```

Also, a jfiddle of my application: http://jsfiddle.net/p15o1kkm/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//Initializing the map
function initialize() {
    var options = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.740337, 22.476279),
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);

    //Loading the GeoJSON file containing the lines
    lines = new google.maps.Data();
    lines.loadGeoJson('http://googledrive.com/host/0B55_4P6vMjhITEU4Ym9iVG8yZUU/lines.geojson');
    lines.setMap(map)

    //Setting the infowindow content
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: '<div class = "corp" style="width: 300px; height: 200px">' + '<div id = "elevation_chart">' + '</div>' + '</div>'
    })

    //Displaying the infowindow when a line is clicked
    lines.addListener('click', function(event) {
        infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng)
        infowindow.setOptions({
            pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(10, -15)
        })
        infowindow.setMap(map);
        drawPath(event.feature.getGeometry().getArray());
    });

    //Invoking the elevation service
    elevator = new google.maps.ElevationService()
}


//Defining the path for which to plot the elevation
function drawPath(path, type) {
    chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('elevation_chart'));

    var pathRequest = {
        'path': path,
        'samples': 256
    };

    var length = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeLength(path);

    elevator.getElevationAlongPath(pathRequest, function(results, status) {
        plotElevation(results, status, length);
    });
}


function plotElevation(results, status, length) {
    if (status != google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) {
        return;
    }

    var elevations = results;

    var elevationPath = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        elevationPath.push(elevations[i].location);
    }

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Sample');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Altitudine');
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        data.addRow(['', elevations[i].elevation]);
    }

    //Setarea stilului graficelor
    document.getElementById('elevation_chart').style.display = 'block';
    chart.draw(data, {
        legend: 'none',
        titleY: 'Elevation (m)',
        titleX: length
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

The important part is obviously

```
var length = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeLength(path);
```

... and the way we call the plotElevation function via an anonymous callback function, so we can also add the path length as well as the results and status arguments.

Comment: That adds a number with the total length of the line under the horizontal axis, but I want it to be displayed something like this: http://velo.caltech.edu/rides/rose_bowl/rose_bowl-elevation.jpg . I think that adding the length somehow with data.addRow will do the trick.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your requirements

Comment: @AlexandruPufan you seem to be using the [older syntax](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart_old) for the Google Charts. I'm assuming they've merely deprecated the data options. However the [new version](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart#Configuration_Options) seems to have more options for configuring the axes, possibly might cover what you need. I'm not really familiar enough with it to say what you need to do